# One admin for multiple sites

Tags: django, django-admin, django-sites

I have two sites with different SITE_IDs, but I want to have only one admin interface for both sites.

I have a model, which is just an extended FlatPage:

```
# models.py
class SFlatPage(FlatPage):
    currobjects = CurrentSiteManager('sites')

    galleries = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery)
    # etc

# admin.py
class SFlatPageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):
    fieldsets = None

admin.site.register(SFlatPage, SFlatPageAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
```

I don't know why, but there are only pages for current site in admin interface. On http://site1.com/admin/ I see flatpages for site1, on http://site2.com/admin/ I see flatpages for site2. But I want to see all pages in http://site1.com/admin/ interface! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the deal with that currobjects Manager? What's your intention for it, and is anything being done with the standard objects manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `CurrentSiteManager`. According to [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#the-currentsitemanager) "it's a model manager that automatically filters its queries to include only objects associated with the current Site."

Remove the line and everyting should work as expected. Or if you make use of `currobjects` somewhere else in your code note that admin interface always use the first manager specified, so you need to specify the standard manager first, like this:

```
# models.py
class SFlatPage(FlatPage):
    objects = models.Manager() # Is first, so will be used by admin
    currobjects = CurrentSiteManager('sites') # your alternative manager

    galleries = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery)
```

Comment: oh, thanks. I've been thinking that my custom manager with custom name won't override the default manager